# Different log4j layout for debug and error?

Tags: java, configuration, logging, log4j

In log4j, is there a way to have logger.error("") and logger.debug("") include different output layouts?

I'd like errors to include method names and line numbers, both of which slow down application performance.

EDIT:

After adding apache-log4j-extras, the following config file works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="WARNINGS" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="warnings.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ERRORS" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="errors.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- %M for method name , %L for line number  -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %M %L - %m%n%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.foo.bar">
        <appender-ref ref="WARNINGS"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ERRORS"/>
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

This code was used to test

```
// goes to errors.txt
     log.error("error");
//goes to warnings.txt
     log.warn("warn");
```

Comment: In your ConversionPattern you may want to use %d{ISO8601} it's an optimized time formatter that log4j provides as a convenience and for speed considerations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within your log4j.xml configuration, you can create two appenders, each using a [LevelMatchFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html) and each with a separate pattern output.

Answer (score 1):

I would just setup two different loggers.  One called ERROR and one called DEBUG.  Then you can easily setup different output layouts and only call ERROR.error or DEBUG.debug.

Comment: Bad advice. Unsuspecting users might follow your advice which would be quite unfortunate.

Comment: If you feel so please tell me why - don't just blindly say something is bad advice without giving better advice.  Why would it be unfortunate?

Comment: The better advice was already given by "Alex B". Calling ERROR.error or DEBUG.debug is pretty dumb. Do read the documentation on log4j or get a clue.

Comment: Even smart  people say stupid  things from time  to time. I  would not
take  my  critical  comments on  your  advice  on  log4j and on  this
particular occasion as personal.

Comment: @Gandalf, this is how I am doing it right now and it didn't like having multiple loggers for a class. It seemed too hacky even for me.