# Log4j: DailyRollingFileAppender with MaxFileSize Option

Tags: log4j

I am using this log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1
# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=D:/MyWeb.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

I want to display logs in the Date Wise Order , so I am using `DailyRollingFileAppender`.
But the issue is that this log file currently cannot hold much data (meaning when lot of requests are made on that day) it looses the previous log data

I tried to use the option `MaxFileSize`:

```
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=10MB
```

But on to the server console its giving error that property `MaxFileSize` isn't supported .

Please tell me if there is any other way that the log appears date wise and it can hold as much data as specified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050615/configuring-multiple-log-files-in-log4j-while-using-categories

Comment: I think the default is 10MB, can anyone confirm? I'm not worried about being able to specify the MaxFileSize as long as there is a reasonable default size that it will roll over even within a day. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could extend the FileAppender class and implement your custom version. More details 
[DailyRollingFileAppender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender)

Comment: Hi Thilakan! Do you know some custom DailyRollingFileAppender implementation with MaxFileSize property? Is that so can you please post that URL as above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `DailyRollingFileAppender` with the hourly backup option. This will rollover the logs every hour.

Hourly Usage:

```
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html), you are using the wrong Appender!

Comment: But RollingFileAppender does not allow you to timestamp the log file name.