# Java-Conversion pattern issues in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Can even tel me how should i change a log 4j conversion pattern for a single log message.
if i change it using the pattern layout class the pattern for the other logmessage in the class is also getting changed.
along with that im getting both patterns. the one in the class and the log4j.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Basically you use 2 different appenders.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008122/different-log4j-layout-for-debug-and-error) is how you do it with a `LevelMatchFilter`, for differentiating `logger.error()` from `logger.warn()` for example.

Comment: Thanx Asaf. I have defined the appender for an error in my log4j.xml file. but for a particular error im changing the conversion pattern.Now in the log file im getting both the messages of the pattern set in the class and the xml filewhere i should get only one error message from the class can u tel me how to rectify this.