# Logging different Level messages in different Logs using Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I want to maintain two Log Files in my web-application using apache Log4j.jar:

1) One log will contain all the Log messages of every level
2) Second log file will contain the Log messages of specific class

This is the configuration XML that I am using: (Not much aware of the tags used in the XML, was just trying out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="FILE1" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="D:/CSVExportLogs/CSVExportLogFile-ERROR.log"/>
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="D:/CSVExportLogs/CSVExportLogFile-INFO.log"/>
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>


<category name="com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager" additivity="false">
<priority value="warn"/>
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</category>

<root>
<priority value="info"/>
<appender-ref ref="FILE1"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

By the above xml I am getting only info messages in the FILE1, I want messages of all levels as well as the message of warn level that are going in the separate file in this file. Is there any solution available for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008122/different-log4j-layout-for-debug-and-error

Comment: Your current config should output everything >= INFO from any class except CustomerManager to FILE1. Everything from CustomerManager >= WARN will go to FILE. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create ROOT logger(main logger) with level INFO, and add to it 2 appenders:
# FILE_INFO, FILE_WARN. This means that all loggers by default will writes messages
# in this 2 file appenders, with level INFO or higher
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE_INFO, FILE_WARN

######## LEVELS:
# Set logging level to WARN for all classes and subclasses in package 
# com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager
log4j.category.com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager=WARN

######## APPENDERS:

# FILE_INFO
# Type of appender
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# File where to save all messages
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.File=D:/CSVExportLogs/CSVExportLogFile-INFO.log
# Max file size, after that will be created new log file, and old file will be renamed
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Maximum amount of old log files.
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.MaxBackupIndex=100
# Patter of messages.
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-24.24t][%32.32c] - %m%n
# Custom level for appender. In this file will be add only messages with level INFO or highter
log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.Threshold=INFO

# FILE_WARN file appender
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.File=D:/CSVExportLogs/CSVExportLogFile-WARN.log
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.MaxFileSize=50KB
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-24.24t][%32.32c] - %m%n
# Custom level for appender. In this file will be add only messages with level WARN or highter
log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.Threshold=WARN
```

Comment: It solves my problem. But would you please explain these properties..Just a short explaination

Comment: I add more comments into the settings.

Comment: log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.Threshold=INFO & log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.Threshold=WARN , Are both comments useful?

Comment: If I need all the messages from com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager, Do I need to make multiple entries?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. log4j.appender.FILE_INFO.Threshold=INFO & log4j.appender.FILE_WARN.Threshold=WARN

Comment: If you need to save all messages from CustomerManager, then change this: log4j.category.com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager=WARN, to the log4j.category.com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager=INFO. Then in CSVExportLogFile-INFO.log you will have all mesages from CustomerManager, and in CSVExportLogFile-WARN.log only WARNs or highter. Also remeber that INFO level is highter than DEBUG and TRACE, so this messages will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

For logging the messages of specific class you could do following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="myClassAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="../logs/myClassLogs.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    .............

    <logger name="com.my.package.MySpecificClass">
        <!-- 
                all log messages of level "debug" or higher will be logged, unless defined otherwise 
                all log messages for "MySpecificClass" will be logged to the appender "myClassAppender"
            -->
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="myClassAppender"/>
    </logger>
    .............
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/05/log4j-tutorial-writing-different-log-levels-in-different-log-files/

Answer (score 0):

I say this act in log4j levels:

```
All < Debug < Info < Warn < Error < Fatal < Off
```

With your configuration, happen thease:

1. All logs with "com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager" category and "Warn" and smaller level("Error" < Fatal) send for "FILE" appender and don't send for "FILE" appender because you set additivity attribute to false for it.
2. All logs with any category except "com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager" send for "FILE1" appender.
   3.You say:"By the above xml I am getting only info messages in the FILE1". You trying logging log with "Warn" or smaller levels(Such as "Error") and "com.taxware.mgmt.CustomerManager" category, you will see result in "FILE" appender and also trying  logging with another category and you will see result in "FILE1" appender, except this result is wrong. please do this and say result.

I also suggest you use SLF4J for decoupling API and implementation.